# drawing circle in the middle of the desktop

Tags: c#, drawing, geometry

heyho folks,

could you please help me to draw a circle in the middle of the desktop.
i am very frustrated about the desktop coordinates.
this is for an overlay

here is my code:

```
Graphics g = default(Graphics);
g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
//g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 200, 200);
int screenmiddlx = this.Width / 2;
int screenmiddly = this.Height / 2;
int kscreenmoddly = Height;
int kscreenmoddlx = Width;

g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, screenmiddlx - 10, screenmiddly, screenmiddlx + 10, screenmiddly);
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, screenmiddlx, screenmiddly - 10, screenmiddlx, screenmiddly + 10);
g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red,,,,);
```

Comment: There isn't an overlay, you'd need to take a screenshot of your desktop and then draw a circle on that bitmap

Comment: here is my code @ the moment:

                Graphics g = default(Graphics);
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            //g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 200, 200);
            int screenmiddlx = this.Width / 2;
            int screenmiddly = this.Height / 2;
            int kscreenmoddly = Height;
            int kscreenmoddlx = Width;

            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, screenmiddlx - 10, screenmiddly, screenmiddlx + 10, screenmiddly);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, screenmiddlx, screenmiddly - 10, screenmiddlx, screenmiddly + 10);
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red,,,,);

Comment: @Janis, please do not post code in comments like that.  Just edit your question.

Comment: //done seems very ugly in comment field

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
        Graphics kp = e.Graphics;
        kp.DrawEllipse(Pen, x, y, width, height);
        // exemple for you:
        kp.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, screenmiddlx, screenmiddly, 20, 20);
```